# Erro de Calculo no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

em um calculo feito em javaScript estou tendo o seguinte problema, já tentei resolver de diversas formas sem sucesso, eu preciso fazer uma operacao matematica simples e no javascript dá uma diferenca de 1 centavo.

o calculo seria = (268.25 - 5.36 + 1.01)
O resultado esperado é 263.90.

porem eu preciso passar nesse resultado uma função que formate com 2 casas decimais sem arredondar ou modificar os dados, por exemplo, se o valor por 2.9999999  funcao teria que retornar 2.99, porem o resultado acima não seria erro de arredondamento visto que o mesmo retorna o numero exato.

Para fazer essa formatação eu uso a função abaixo:

```
function toFixed(num, fixed) {
    fixed = fixed || 0;
    fixed = Math.pow(10, fixed);
    return Math.floor(num * fixed) / fixed;
}
```

quando o total é passado por ela o valor retornado é 263.89, gerando essa diferença de 1 centavo.

Comment: Já tentou usar a função toFixed nativa do javascript?

Comment: Quais são os valores que você passa em `num` e `fixed`?

Comment: A função  "toFIxed" nativa não resolve o teu problema?

Answer (score 1):

**O `.toFixed` pode talvez não resolver o problema**, porque em alguns casos ele vai "arredondar" alguns valores e o que você parece necessitar é aparar o numero, então o que você precisa **é tratar como string**

**Possivelmente seu** o objetivo é adicionar um zero a "frente" também, além de aparar as casas decimais, pois creio que tenha a intenção de exibir isto para o usuário, então um exemplo que não arredondaria:

```js
var x = 268.25,
    y = 5.36,
    z = 1.01;

console.log("Calculo:", x - y + z);

var para_exibir = String(x - y + z) + "0";

console.log("Para o usuário/imprimir:", para_exibir);
```

Claro que se o valor for algo como `2.9999` terá que aparar, então você pode usar uma função para checar se o tamanho do decimal é maior que "uma casa" e assim aparar ou completar a string, por exemplo:

```
function formatar(f, precisao) {
   f = String(f);

   var i = f.indexOf(".");

   if (i > -1) {
       var d = f.substr(i + 1),    //Pega somente as casas decimais
           n = f.substr(0, i + 1); //Pega o valor "inteiro"

       if (d.length < precisao) { // Se for menor que duas casas adiciona o zero
          f = n + d + ("0".repeat(precisao - 1)); /*o -1 é porque neste caso já deve ter um digito na casa, então só adiciona os zeros que faltam*/
       } else if (d.length > precisao) { // Se for maior que duas casas apara a string sem arredondar o valor
          f = n + f.substr(i + 1, precisao);
       }
   }

   return f;
}
```

O uso é:

> ```
> formatar ( int valor , int precisao )
> ```

Exemplo:

```js
var x = 268.25,
    y = 5.36,
    z = 1.01;


function formatar(f, precisao) {
    f = String(f);

    var i = f.indexOf(".");

    if (i > -1) {
        var d = f.substr(i + 1),
            n = f.substr(0, i + 1);

        if (d.length < precisao) {
            f = n + d + ("0".repeat(precisao - 1));
        } else if (d.length > precisao) {
            f = n + f.substr(i + 1, precisao);
        }
    }

    return f;
}

//Com "precisão" de duas casas
console.log("10.9999 formatado:", formatar(10.9999, 2) );
console.log("10.9 formatado:", formatar(10.9, 2) );
console.log("10.99 formatado:", formatar(10.99, 2) );
console.log("x - y + z formatado:", formatar(x - y + z, 2) );

console.log("-----------");

//Com "precisão" de três casas
console.log("10.4445 formatado:", formatar(10.4445, 3) );
console.log("10.4 formatado:", formatar(10.4, 3) );
console.log("10.455 formatado:", formatar(10.455, 3) );
console.log("x - y + z formatado:", formatar(x - y + z, 3) );
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma que funcionou para o que eu precisava foi essa:

```
function numberFormatPrecision(number, format) {   
    var number = number.toFixed(3);
    return number.substring(0, number.length - 1);
}
```

Comment: Falta explicar o porque e como funciona né? Se não fica com cara de suporte e as pessoas ficam sem entender a lógica, pois muitas vezes a lógica pode ser aproveitada para inumeros outros casos, como alguém que precisasse que `2.9998888` vira-se `2.9999`, com 3 casas.

Comment: Em um software tínhamos a necessidade de trabalhar com um numero com duas casas decimais sem que sofresse arredondamento, resumidamente ele formata com uma casa a mais e depois usa substring para remover o ultimo carácter, assim um valor 5.996  não viraria 6 e sim 5.99.

Comment: Caro Victor, por favor coloque isso no corpo da resposta, sua resposta pode ajudar futuros visitantes, entenda que o site aqui não é como um fórum de suportes, é algo que tentamos tornar proveitoso para todos, a sua duvida de hoje pode ser a solução para uma futura pessoa com o mesmo problema. Por favor, adicione a explicação técnica do que ocorre no código e explique o porque ele funciona.